# Trying to create simple JavaScript slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery

The slideshow will rotate among six images 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg 5.jpg 6.jpg

```
var showarray = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg"];

var i = 0;

for( i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
{
    // How can I make this script wait for two seconds in this spot
    // so the pic is displayed for two seconds? 

    document.getElementById("imageid").src = showarray[i];
    if(i == 5) i = 0;

}
```

I am also including jQuery in this page if that is another way.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) method. Call it like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   // change the source of the image here.
}, 1000 /* 1 SECOND */);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to make it sleep for two seconds. This would take away control from the browser and is pretty bad. Try something like this (I'm bad at JS):

```
var showarray = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg"];
var i = 0;
var newPic;

newPic = function() {
  i = i+1 % 6;
  document.getElementById("imageid").src = showarray[i];
  setTimeout(newPic, 2000);
}

newPic();
```